# jndi object bind life span

Tags: java, bind, jndi

I have binded an object to my jndi in my web application. If I close the browser and do not unbind my context or close it the object is still 'bound' to the jndi, so my 2 question are :

how does the life cycle of an object bind work? I would assume it lasts as long as the jvm instance is up.

Is there any way to unbind an object once a user closes the browser?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends entirely on which namespace you are talking about. LDAP is persistent. RMI's lifetime is the life of the Registry. Corba's is the life of the tnameserv or orbd! unless you are using a persistent naming service. The java: namespace is provided by the container and has the same lifespan.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't have a way to now if the user closes the browser. What's the difference of leaving your page? If you are using sessions then you could un-bind when the session expires.  Use `unbind` to unbind.